# ms-Excel Worksheet transfer between worksbooks and vlookup

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple problem(at least seems to be) that I just cannot seem to be able to find a good solution to:

I have 4 workbooks, that all contain two of the exact worksheets(rest of the worksheets are unique for each workbook). I am storing these two worksheets in a seperate workbook(so 5th workbook). Out of these 2 worksheets, 1 of them is a Data sheet made up of many tables, which I do updates on and the other one is a sheet called V, which just uses some vlookup functions to bring up the related data from this Data sheet.

I am trying to find a way to be able to pass along this data sheet to each individual workbook, instead of editing the data sheet individually for each workbook(All 4 of them).

I was able to come up with the following macro, which checks if the sheet already exists and if it does it deletes it. Then it opens up location of the excel file, copies this worksheet to the workbook and therefore I have  the most "updated" version of this data worksheet.

```
Sub UpdateT()

Sheets("data").Visible = True

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim aw As Workbook
''Open 2nd Workbook
Set aw = Application.ActiveWorkbook

'Check if data worksheet exists, and if it does delete it
If Not GetWorksheet("data") Is Nothing Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("data").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

'Check if T worksheet exists, and if it does, delete it
If Not GetWorksheet("T") Is Nothing Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("T").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\yilmadu001\Desktop\Update.xlsx")

'Copy To Different Workbook
wb.Sheets("data").Copy _
     After:=aw.Sheets("Data1")
wb.Sheets("5120 TI").Copy _
     After:=aw.Sheets("MENU5120")

'Close 2nd Workbook
aw.Save
wb.Close

'Hide the data worksheet
aw.Sheets("data").Visible = False

End Sub

'Function to check if worksheets exist
Function GetWorksheet(shtName As String) As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWorksheet = Worksheets(shtName)
End Function
```

The problem is the following:

When the new Data worksheet is transferred, the V worksheet is no longer working with the Vlookup function to be able to point to the relative information. So then I thought, okay what if I transfer BOTH Data and V worksheets, however that also did not work.

Is there a way to be able to use Vlookup, while copying the Data sheet? (The name is exactly the same I do not understand why it does not seem to be able to point to the cells of the table). It just looks blank, can't point to anything.

NOTE: I am not changing the format of the Data tables, basically just the values, so the format is the exactly the same.

It is probably important to note that the main excel workbooks(the 4) are in use 24/7, therefore I cannot go the other way(Update from Data workbook to the main workbook). I must "pull" the updated worksheet rather than "push".

If anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: VLOOKUP will work if you don't delete/insert the whole sheet, but only the data. So define the used range of that sheet, clear it, then copy/paste the data from the updated version. 
As soon as you delete the sheet, all the VLOOKUP formulas lose their references and reset to an error state. What you do after deletion has no effect.

Comment: @ComradeMicha thank you for your comment, but what if I am not sure which table I will be updating? (I guess I could copy/paste the information on all the tables?)

Comment: if you have 4 workbooks with known ranges to reference, or at least have a clear indicator for the beginning of each table, you should be able to code so that the source data sheets information is reference and then updated on your filtered sheet.  You could get to that end result numerous ways, where the final output sheet pulls data from other workbooks.  This will all rely on how the source data is laid out, so you can prgrammatically find the rest of the data you need/want.